# New WP installation due to language issues

Tags: installation, multi-language

My current WP installation is in English, I dowloaded the theme (So cute by YIT)
My objective is to set up a store in swedish. I've been struggeling to translate strings etc, I've tried the WPML plugin and I also tried creating new .mo and .po files with Poedit according to general recommendations.
I have now decided to use the Swedish WP installation and my question before I do this is if I simply can overwrite current English files via FTP? There is a wp-config-sample.php in the new installation file but I guess this serves no function as I have the original wp-config.php with the correct "define" settings plus database settings etc? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a Swedish version of WordPress although they do provide a convenient package that has the language files already loaded. The only differences from the core (English) distribution are the folder `wp-content/languages`, the variable `$wp_local_package = 'sv_SE';` set in `wp-includes/version.php`, the localized `readme.html` file and the `wp-config-sample.php` file.

So yes, you should be safe uploading directly on top of your current install as long as you upload the same version number (3.9.2 to 3.9.2 or 3.9.1 to 3.9.1).

The file `wp-config-sample.php` has PHP comments localized to your language so you can either update the variables in that file from your current `wp-config.php` and just rename it or you can just set `define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');` in your current config file if your fine with comments in English.